# How to save a view in BigQuery - Standard SQL Dialect

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to save a view using BigQuery's WebUI, which was created in Standard SQL Dialect, but I am getting this error:

**Failed to save view. Bad table reference "myDataset.myTable"; table references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs**

Why is this error showing up? How can I fix it? Should the "Table ID" field of the "Save view" dialog include the project id? Or does this error appear because of the query itself? Just in case, the query is running without any problems.

[image: BigQuery's Save View]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your view has reference to `myDataset.myTable` - which is ok when you just run it as a query (for example in Web UI).

But to save it as a view you must fully qualify that reference as below

```
myProject.myDataset.myTable
```

So, just add project to that reference

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mikhail, I am not sure where I should add this reference. I tried to add it in the SQL query: "from adept-storm-142922.summarytables.pendingClasses20172"  but there is a new error " Syntax error: Unexpected "-" at [10:14]"  It seems that you cannot use the "-" symbol in it.

Comment: @Milton - exactly! and you need to use backticks. like "from \`adept-storm-142922.summarytables.pendingClasses20172\`". looks like now you have there just "from summarytables.pendingClasses20172"

Comment: Mikhail, it is working fine now.  Thanks for you help!! @Mikhail

Comment: I don't know if this is new, but I get this when I try to enter anything with a dot in into the Table ID field: `Table IDs may contain letters, numbers, and underscores`

Comment: @Stephen using dots in table names is not supported because it gets confused with the namespace separator dot between project.dataset.table

Comment: It took awhile to understand what this answer meant. I'd encourage to modify the original answer. "select field from `GCP_project_name.dataset_name.table_name`"

Answer (score 2):

> Same reply, in other words

The issue is in this part of query: **FROM com.table**

When running query, it's fine to not fully specify the name of table like this:

```
com_company_app_beta_IOS.app_events_20180619
```

But to save the query as a view the **FROM** has to be like this:

```
`company-prod`.com_company_app_beta_IOS.app_events_20180619
```

You need the backticks around the `` `company-prod` `` because the `-` dash character is unsupported in object names.

The structure in BigQuery look like this:
[bigquery ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSYEx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
You'll need to use backticks around the the whole string project.dataset.view/table in both create and select statements:

create view `company-prod.com_company_app_beta_IOS.YOUR_VIEW` as
select * from `company-prod.com_company_app_beta_IOS.app_events_20180619`

[Use backticks around string project.dataset.view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmyIj.png)